# How to resolve conflict between ncurses and std input/output in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, input, blocking, pdcurses

I'm working on a multi thread application in which there is a main and a secondary thread.
Secondary thread has to take input by the user and giving the result to the main thread, the problem is that std::cin is a blocking function, this means that if main thread stop its execution secondary thread can't do the same due to `std::cin`.
User has to enter something to let the program end and I would like to overcome this problem.
So basically the pseudo-code is this:

```
std::atomic<bool> interrupt(false);

std::string get_input(){

  std::cout << "Insert a new command: ";
  std::string cmd;
  std::cin >> cmd;
  return cmd;

  }

void kill_main_thread(){

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5000));
  interrupt = true;

  }
int main() {

  std::thread new_thread (kill_main_thread);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()


  while(1) {

      if ( interrupt ) {
          return 0;
      }

      std::future<std::string> fut = std::async(get_input);
      if ( fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(500)) == std::future_status::timeout ){

          std::string cmd = fut.get();

            
           if ( cmd == "close") {...}
            else if ( cmd == "open") {...}
            else {...}

      }

  }
return 0;
  
}
```

Unfourtunately I can't change the execution flow of my program, so based on a previous question I decide to use `PDCurses` library for the presence of `getch()` that allow me the create an input non blocking function.

```
std::string input(){

    initscr();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
    char ch;
    std::string cmd = "";

    while(!interrupt) {
        if ((ch = getch()) != ERR)
            cmd = cmd + ch;

        if ( ch == '\n') break;
    }
    endwin();
    return cmd;
}
```

In this way by replacing this `input` function with `std::cin` of the previous example, by setting interrupt to true I'm able to stop execution of the seconary thread.
The problem is that PDCurses get in conflicts with all std::cout of my program, terminal don't work correctly with standard library.
I found three different solution to overcome this problem:

1.) Defining a new terminal in which I active PDCurses on it and another one that have to work with std. Althought `newterm`should create a new terminal this function don't work:

```
    ....
    FILE *f = fopen("/dev/tty", "r+");
    SCREEN *screen = newterm(NULL, f, f);
    set_term(screen);
    refresh();
    ....
```

2.) Using just `getch()`function, by avoiding console manipulation of PDCurses. But I didn't find a solution for this.

3.) Defining in another way a non blocking input function.

Comment: Mixing `std::cin/std::cout` I/O with `curses` I/O is probably not a good idea. Use the `curses` I/O only.

Comment: I agree wtih you, unfortunately in order to work, getch function need initscr() and initscr() affect both input and output.
I checked all documentation to find some way to use only pdcurses input, but I didn't find it

Comment: `wgetch`, `mwgetch` and `mvwgetch`?

Comment: they work on a window, they don't refer to terminals.

Comment: Exactly. If you use `curses` - _only_ use `curses` for I/O.